# Change installed packages after install for Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio, vs-community-edition

I installed VS Community 2015, and selected custom options. I realised afterwards I didn't include some options I need - my solution includes C# web-services and these are listed as incompatible.

Can I see the list of installed modules and modify them post-install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can go to *Add or remove programs* and **Modify**:

[image]

Comment: Cool, I was trying to find it from within VS but this looks ideal